# Issue with Firebase on expo project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, expo

Whenever I click the submit button on my code to upload data to my firebase database, I get this error :

`ERROR  [2024-01-21T03:39:39.733Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.7.2): INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined`

i have tried uninstalling the node modules and specifically firebase but nothing is working. I tried making a new firebase account and it still doesn't work. I cannot figure it out.

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';
import { getFirestore, doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import app from '../config/FirebaseConfig'; // Adjust this path as necessary

const DataInput = () => {
  const [monthOrderTotal, setMonthOrderTotal] = useState('');
  const [monthDollarAmount, setMonthDollarAmount] = useState('');

  const firestore = getFirestore(app);
  const auth = getAuth();

  const handleSave = async () => {
    const user = auth.currentUser;
    if (user) {
      try {
        const userData = {
          monthOrderTotal,
          monthDollarAmount
        };
        // Merge the new data into the existing document or create a new document if it doesn't exist
        await setDoc(doc(firestore, 'users', user.uid), userData, { merge: true });
        console.log('Data saved successfully');
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error saving data: ', error);
      }
    } else {
      console.error('No user logged in');
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Data Input Screen</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Month Order Total"
        value={monthOrderTotal}
        onChangeText={setMonthOrderTotal}
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
      <TextInput
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder="Month Dollar Amount"
        value={monthDollarAmount}
        onChangeText={setMonthDollarAmount}
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
      <Button title="Save" onPress={handleSave} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default DataInput;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
  input: {
    height: 40,
    margin: 12,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
    width: '80%'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

It's an issue with Firestore 10.7.2
Just downgrade to version 10.7.1 and it should work fine.
[Check this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7962)

Comment: Tried with downgrading to 10.7.1 but not sure why it was still not working for me on Expo SDK50. Although it did worked flawlessly for version ^9.17.1

Answer (score 1):

It's a known issue with the latest release, it now has been resolved and the fix will come in the next release. One way to fix it is to rollback to a previous version i.e. 10.7.1 or if the isssue persists like mine you can just add this line of code:

```
window.navigator.userAgent = "ReactNative";
```

I pasted mine inside the App.js file before any firebase related import.

Edited to add credits:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7962#issuecomment-1902290249

Answer (score 0):

***Here is the solution for the question:***

This error happens, because of the firebase new version. The Version 10.7.2 has some problems.

1. First got to app.json file.
2. Then find the firebase.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzSKg.png)
3. You need to remove `^, ~` marks from the version if they exists and change the version to 10.7.1. After edit it should be like this.

   `"firebase": "10.7.1"`
4. Then delete the node modules directory(Folder).
5. Finally, install node modules again using below command.

   `npm install`

Then run `npm start` or `npx expo start` or `npx expo start --tunnel` what ever you normally does.

1. If there will new error happens like **"firebase/firestore not found"**. For this error you can simply run `npm install firebase/firestore`.

You are all set. The error will not anymore and you can work with your app.

Thanks,
Tharanga Madurapperuma.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue because expo maintains a separate install folder (or something) from npm. I don't know the specifics.

To address the `Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined` error, the following command fixed it for me:

```bash
npx expo install firebase
```

Answer (score -2):

```bash
function HomeView() {
    
      const navigation = useNavigation();
      const addDocument = async () => {
        try {
          const docRef = await addDoc(collection(firestore, "your_collection"), {
            field1: "value1",
            field2: "value2",
          });
          console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <View className="flex justify-center items-center relative top-60">
          <Text> D-ALERT LOGO </Text>
    
          <TouchableOpacity className="ml-5 mt-60"
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.navigate("Login")
              }}
            >
              <Text className="text-blue-500 text-lg font-bold">LOG IN</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
    
    
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> addDocument()}>
                  <View>
                      <Text>test</Text>
                  </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      )
    }
```

i had the same issue

```bash
 ERROR  [2024-01-21T08:07:48.756Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.7.2): INTERNAL UNHANDLED ERROR:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
    at isSafari
```