# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined

Tags: firebase, react-native, authentication, google-cloud-firestore, expo

I have an expo application that works with Firebase, but for some time now I can no longer interact with Firebase to connect or register, I get this error all the time;

```
 WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 1):
TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
    at isSafari (http://192.168.1.11:8081/node_modules/expo-router/entry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:214158:53)
    at __PRIVATE_getDefaultRelativeIndexReadCostPerDocument (http://192.168.1.11:8081/node_modules/expo-
 ERROR  [2024-01-30T12:31:02.312Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.7.2): FIRESTORE (10.7.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state
 ERROR  [Error: FIRESTORE (10.7.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state]
 ERROR  [2024-01-30T12:31:02.333Z]  @firebase/firestore: Firestore (10.7.2): FIRESTORE (10.7.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state
 LOG  [Error: FIRESTORE (10.7.2) INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Unexpected state]
```

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watch --coverage=false --changedSince=origin/main",
    "testDebug": "jest -o --watch --coverage=false",
    "testFinal": "jest",
    "updateSnapshots": "jest -u --coverage=false"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)"
    ],
    "transform": {}
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@pietile-native-kit/page-slider": "^1.2.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "7.2.0",
    "@shopify/flash-list": "1.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.11",
    "@types/recoil": "^0.0.9",
    "expo": "^49.0.21",
    "expo-checkbox": "~2.4.0",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-image": "~1.3.5",
    "expo-image-manipulator": "~11.3.0",
    "expo-image-picker": "~14.3.2",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-localization": "~14.3.0",
    "expo-router": "^2.0.14",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "firebase": "^10.7.1",
    "i18n-js": "^4.2.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~49.0.0",
    "lottie-react-native": "5.1.6",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.6",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-gifted-chat": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-maps": "1.7.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-shimmer-placeholder": "^2.0.9",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-toast-message": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.6",
    "recoil": "^0.7.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.23.3",
    "@expo/webpack-config": "^19.0.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.4.3",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.14",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.72.8",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "^5.1.3"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I tried to upgrade to version 50 of the SDK, changed my config, but nothing worked, I feel like I've covered what I knew how to do in terms of debugging

Comment: I fix my isssue :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77853549/issue-with-firebase-on-expo-project

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue with the latest release, it now has been resolved and the fix will come in the next release. One way to fix it is to rollback to a previous version i.e. 10.7.1 or if the isssue persists like mine you can just add this line of code:

```
window.navigator.userAgent = "ReactNative";
```

I pasted into my project inside the App.js file before any firebase related import.

As per Yonom: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/7962#issuecomment-1902290249

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).